# When "as" and "though" are used to introduce concession clauses

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, inversion, as, concessives

When "as" is used to introduce a concession clause, the clause has be inverse. For example, "Young as he is, he is knowledgeable".

I am wondering whether I can replace "though" with "as" in these situations.

Do the following sentences sound natural?

> 1a: Talented as he is, he is not yet ready to turn professional.
>
> 1b: Talented though he is, he is not yet ready to turn professional.
>
> 2a: Try as he might, he couldn't open the door.
>
> 2b: Try though he might, he couldn't open the door.
>
> 3a: Lazy a boy as he is, he is kind to help others.
>
> 3b: Lazy a boy though he is, he is kind to help others.
>
> 4a: Oldest in our workshop as he is, he works hardest.
>
> 4b: Oldest in our workshop though he is, he works hardest.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AmE - I have not heard "though" used this way before. Maybe its literery? Anyway, could you add a reference describing such usage?

Comment: Not inverse, but it follows a set pattern. This answer might be helpful - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47554/3463

Comment: 1a and 1b is synonymous. The expression - *try as he might* - is a set expression. 2a and 2b is synonymous. I am not sure about 2b. 3a and 3b is not correct. 4a and 4b also is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my native speaker's take on which sound natural and which don't:

> 1a: Talented as he is, he is not yet ready to turn professional. *[Natural.]*
>
> 1b: Talented though he is, he is not yet ready to turn professional. *[Natural.]*
>
> 2a: Try as he might, he couldn't open the door. *[Natural.]*
>
> 2b: Try though he might, he couldn't open the door. *[Unnatural.]*
>
> 3a: Lazy a boy as he is, he kindly helps others. *[Unnatural, possibly ungrammatical. I changed the part after the comma to be grammatical; I assume that's not what you're asking about.]*
>
> 3b: Lazy a boy though he is, he kindly helps others. *[Unnatural, possibly ungrammatical.]*
>
> 4a: Oldest in our workshop as he is, he works hardest. *[Unnatural.]*
>
> 4b: Oldest in our workshop though he is, he works hardest. *[Unnatural.]*

Below are some speculations about what's going on.

### Familiar phrases

The words **as** and **though** appear in various familiar phrases, or phrase templates. The opening clauses in the sentences above echo them more or less strongly, contributing to their perception as natural, unnatural, grammatical, and ungrammatical. First I'll list all the familiar phrases that I see being echoed, and then I'll explain how they accord or clash with the sentences above.

(A) ***X* as he is** can be understood as a short form of **As *x* as he is** when *x* is a quality that comes in degrees.

(B) ***Trait* as he is** can be understood as ***Trait,* as he is,** or as an inversion of **As he is *trait***, when *trait* is a quality that you either do or don't have. In other words, this reading is the same as **Since he is *trait***.

(C) ***Trait* though he is** can be understood as an inversion of **Though he is *trait***, where *trait* is a quality that you either do or don't have.

(D) ***Verb* as he might** can be understood as **Try as he might try** or **As he might try**, that is: in whatever manner he might try.

(E) **Try as he might** is itself a stock phrase.

(F) ***Verb* though he might** can be understood as an inversion of **Though he might *verb*.** This means that you're thinking of *verb* as something you do or don't do, not as something that you can do in a variety of manners.

### How well the sentences accord with the phrases they echo

(1) You can understand **talented** as either a quality that comes in degrees or a trait that you do or don't have, so (1a) accords with both (A) and (B). There is some contradiction between (A) and (B), but I think ordinarily a listener doesn't notice and just rides along to the clause after the comma. (1b) matches (C), so it's easy to hear that way, but **talented** is mainly a quality that comes in degrees, so (1b) is just a little off.

(2a) is a perfect match with the stock phrase (E), so it gets a free pass. There's no bending or varying going on. (2b) seems to echo (F), but if you take **couldn't** as past tense, then it doesn't make sense: "Though he might try, he was not able to open the door." However, **couldn't** is pretty flexible with regard to time, so there are reasonable interpretations: "Though he might try, he won't be able to open the door." Because (2b) uses the word **try**, though, it seems to clash with (E). (E) is a strong attractor, so failing to match it can feel like a grammatical error even if technically it isn't.

(3a) echoes (A) too weakly to be easily understood as "As lazy a boy as he is"; "lazy a boy" doesn't fit *x* in the formula, though you could hear it that way. Maybe you could understand it through (B), "As [since] he is a lazy boy", but I think it's very hard to hear it that way. You *could* understand (3b) grammatically through (C), as a scrambled version of "Though he is a lazy boy," which is that sentence's only claim to grammaticality. The most obvious unscrambling comes out as "Though he is lazy a boy," which doesn't make sense.

(4a) echoes (B) and (4b) echoes (C) pretty clearly, since **oldest** is a superlative and doesn't come in degrees. I feel a little disoriented, though, because in an unscrambled version you'd precede **oldest** with **the**: "As he is the oldest in our workshop" or "Though he is the oldest in our workshop". It's *okay* to drop the article in the unscrambled versions, and certainly the scrambled versions cannot take an article, so the result is a feeling of clumsiness and a suspicion of ungrammaticality.

Answer (score 1):

In these types of concession clauses, "though" and "as" are synonyms. So your examples work.

This is not the case in e.g., comparison clauses: "I am *as* smart *as* you."

But you cannot say, "I am though smart though you" (and still make sense).

Answer (score 1):

*3a: Lazy a boy as he is, he is kind to help others.

3b: Lazy a boy though he is, he is kind to help others.*

As a note, "he is kind to help others" is not grammatical. You could say "he is keen to help others" (using the definition of "keen" that means "eager"), or you could say "he is kind and helps others."

*4a: Oldest in our workshop as he is, he works hardest.

4b: Oldest in our workshop though he is, he works hardest.*

While these may be equally grammatical (or equally ungrammatical, in the case of the original #3), people would generally not use this sentence construction -- adding the longer phrases "Lazy a boy" or "oldest in our workshop" makes the "as/though he is" part confusing. These would be restructured to "Though he's a lazy boy, he is kind and helps others," or "Though he is the oldest in our workshop, he works the hardest." The "as he is" version would not be used at all, in my experience, because it's awkward phrasing.

You could say "Lazy as he is" (without the "a boy"), but "oldest in our workshop" is just too long to rearrange comfortably. Using the sentence in 4b would get Yoda jokes. (Canonical Yoda joke: "Backwards to speak teach you will I.")

Comment: Thanks :) any idea for 2a and 2b? can we use any other verb with **as/though** this way illustrated in sentence 2#?

Comment: 2a and 2b are fine; I would expect to hear 2a more frequently, but 2b won't ring as "weird" to my ears. (And, as an editor, I would not bother correcting it unless I had a character limit.) I would slightly prefer 1b to 1a in text, as the intended meaning of 1a becomes a *little* ambiguous without voice cues. (It could be sarcasm, saying he's *not* talented enough to be pro.) Other verbs in the #2 format? All the synonyms for "try" (struggle, strive, etc.) to start. More than the comments section will allow now, definitely.

Comment: Hmm, both 3b and 4b seem decidedly ungrammatical to my native ear :(

Comment: Were I editing those, I would change them because they're too confusing and sound bad. It's quite possible that they're grammatical in the same way that people joke that "'ghoti' spells 'fish.'"