# Usages of "as" and "although" with approximately the same meaning

Tags: conjunctions

> A. Huge boulders, **far too big to be used as they were**, were lying throughout the bed of the quarry.

and

> B. Huge boulders,  **although they were far too big to be used**, were
>   lying throughout the bed of the quarry.

Would anyone please show me if, especially semantically, there is any difference between the two bold parts?

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATED***: For clarification I had to edit my question. My Prof. has just shown me the following is correct and means the same thing. WOULD The sentences A and B, therefore, mean the same thing, as well? if so,why? why not?

1.**Although it may seem straightforward, the argument is indefensible.**

2.**Straightforward as it may seem, the argument is indefensible.**

Comment: In your first sentence "as" doesn't mean "although". If you want to know what you mentioned in title, please use a dictionary. Any online dictionary will help :)

Comment: Yes your prof is right. And in your last sentence **as** indeed mean **although**. But please be careful how **as** is used in that sentence. Any dictionary will be helpful for this kind of question.

Comment: @Man_From_India Please can you tell us a particular dictionary that will be helpful for this question. Helpful ***as*** your comment might seem, it isn't really helpful:D

Comment: @Araucaria Another example where **as** means **although**

Comment: @Araucaria I have checked Oxford dictionary. It's doesn't say what pattern it should follow for **as** to mean **although**, but there are example sentences that is helpful. In collins learner's dictionary it clearly states how **as** should be used to mean **although**.

Answer (score 5):

"as", and "although" aren't interchangeable. Consider the following:

> **although** they were far too big to be used **as they were**

You can combine both and it still means the same thing. The core statement is "they were far to big to be used", and I can add the word *although* to say that there's something wrong with them, and I can add the phrase *as they were* to say "in their current state".

Let's do an experiment and apply my logic to your update:

> Although it may seem as straightforward as it may seem...

Okay the repetition sounds quite strange, but the meaning has been preserved. The core idea you're trying to get across is 'it may seem straightforward', and you can use either (or both) **although** and **as** to get the same effect. **Although** goes at the beginning of the clause and **as** goes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Huge boulders, **far too big to be used as they were**, were lying throughout the bed of the quarry.

The bold part gives a *reason* of why the boulders were "lying" at the quarry. "As they were" means in **that** state of theirs. Hmm, sensible is this sentence and it can be used in a normal context.

> Huge boulders, **although they were far too big to be used**, were lying throughout the bed of the quarry.

If it was me who attempted to write this sentence **with an "although"**, I would have omitted "they were" and changed the sentence to

> Huge boulders, although far too big to be used, were lying throughout the bed of the quarry.

Anyway, that's not the point here. The point is, **you have possibly misunderstood their meanings**. "Although" is used to demonstrate contrasts. I as the listener would expect to see something like this after the phrase with "although":

> Although they were far too big to be used, *workers wasted a dear amount of precious time trying to make them work.*

There's no way "as" will be used to show contrasts the way this context is written. And reputable grammar sites or dictionaries can teach you almost all of the usages "as" can have.

Answer (score 1):

When **as** means although, it takes some set pattern:

**adjective/adverb** + *as* + clause

> d. **Cold as/though it was**, we went out. ( = Although it was cold, we went out)
>
> e. **Tired as/though I was**, I went on working.
>
> f. **Bravely as/though they fought**, they had no chance of winning.

Note that **as** in those structures can also mean **because**. The context will tell you if **as** means **because** or **although**.

> **Tired as she was**, I decided not to disturb her. ( = I decided not to disturb her, because she was tired)

In AmE *as...as* is normally used in this structure.

> **As cold as it was**, we went out.

---

> **From Advanced Learner's Dictionary -**
>
> **As**
>
> (*conjunction*) in the way in which
>
> **Example**
>
> > *They did as I had asked.*
> >
> > *Leave the papers as they are.*

Your sentence #A

> Huge boulders, far too big to be used **as they were**, were lying throughout the bed of the quarry.

Here **they were** means **they appear** or **their appearance**

So this sentence means *Huge boulders were lying throughout the bed of the quarry. Those huge boulders are far too big, and not suitable to be used in the way in which they appear*.

Your sentence #2

> **Straightforward as it may seem**, the argument is indefensible.

**Straightforward as it may seem** follows the same pattern **adjective/adverb** + *as* + clause

And so here **as** means **although**. This sentence means **Although it may seem straightforward, the argument is indefensible**.

I believe you have no problem understanding sentence #1 and sentence #B.

Comment: Hi, man from India. Which of those sentences do you mean?

Comment: Additionally, I have numbered the sentences so as to refer to them more readily.

Comment: @nima I am sorry for the confusion. I edited my answer. Sentence #A and sentence #B are not similar in meaning, and in sentence #A, **as** doesn't mean **although**. Though after you have read the answer, you could have told which sentences I was talking about :P

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, what about the sentences 1 and 2? while the sentences A and B are not similar in meaning, why sentences 1 and 2 are similar in meaning??

Comment: @nima Why sentence #1 and #2 is similar? :O Are you kidding? :D :D My answer just tell it why!! And if you can understand it, you can also answer why sentence #A and #B is not similar in meaning. You better answer reaing my answer once again, why sentence #1 and sentence #2 is similar in emaning?

Comment: SO, does the sentence"e" equal with" though she was tired, I decided not to disturb?

Comment: @nima Sentence #e is different. **Tired as she was, I decided not to disturb her** means **Because she was tired, I decided not to disturb her.** As I said both **because** or **although** can be meant through this kind of structure. The deciding factor is the meaning/context. Here in this sentence - **Tired as she was, I decided not to disturb her** - we possibly can't get the meaning of **although**

Comment: @nima Please consider the meaning also whenever you try some grammatical structure because it's important and depending on the meaning many a things change. If you really want to learn why your sentence #1 and #2 is similar in meaning, please go through my answer over again and please comment back your answer why you  and other for that matter think they are similar in meaning? It's really simple. Unless you make an effort to learn (be it an answer or whatever), asking questions or providing bounty will not help you at all. If you can't understand an answer keep commenting below it :)

Comment: Thanks alot. Nevertheless, unfortunetly, I cannot get what you are showing me at all. I have no idea at the time, man-from-India

Comment: @nima In my answer I just showed you the pattern in which "as" means "although". But I put a note that "as" in those structure can't only mean "although", they can also mean "because"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20536/discussion-between-man-from-india-and-nima).

Comment: @Araucaria and nima, I am reeally sorry. Not only I was wrong in saying the right meaning, I was also wrong in stating the parts of speech of **as** in that sentence :( I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example sentence "as" is a function word for comparison.
"although" expresses contrast, opposion. Both ideas make sense but 
they are different ideas.

Answer (score 1):

These sentences have one thing in common: their full meaning includes a "but" or "however", even though the sentences haven't been constructed to use those words directly.

Here's how I might paraphrase the first pair of sentences:

> Huge boulders were lying throughout the bed of the quarry, but they were far too big to be used.

and the second:

> The argument may seem straightforward, but it is indefensible.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a semantic difference between the two bold parts, but there are many ways these two sentences can be reworded. One way is to put the second part of the sentence first. In the first case, that can be done rather easily using *although*. Remember, *although* works like *however*, but *although* often works better when you are introducing the "however" part first, like this:

> Although they were far too big to be used, huge boulders were lyaing throughout the quarry bed.

The second sentence is a bit trickier, because of the "may seem" part:

> Although it is indefensible, the argument may seem straigtforward.

This does not work very well, because of the "may seem" part. The construct:

> Although X, Y

works fine, but:

> Although X, maybe Y

can sound rather odd.

That leads us to your last pair of sentences:

> 1. Although it may seem straightforward, the argument is indefensible.
> 2. Straightforward as it may seem, the argument is indefensible.

Both of these essentially mean:

> The argument is indefensible, even though it might appear to be straightforward.

Comment: So, both of them 1 and 2 mean the same thing?

Comment: @nima - seems that way to me, but that has a lot to do with the order of the words.

Comment: I don't think that's what the first sentence means! I think it means "*Far too big to be used in their present state, ...*"

Comment: @Araucaria - No doubt that is a valid interpretation of the first sentence.