# what does " may have been to figure" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

She was my best friend, and hard **as it may have been  to figure by the looks of us**, she was the good girl, I the bad.

Would anyone please teach me what the bold part mean simply?

Meanwhile, I think you remove was in the situation- I was the bad, don't you?

Thanks

Comment: Is not this similar, if not duplicate, to your earlier question? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/usages-of-as-and-although-with-approximately-the-same-meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Figure* here means "To come to understand" or "to deduce" [(meaning #2)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/figure#Verb).

So "hard as it may have been to come to understand by the looks of us" – or simply, "hard as it been to know."